# Getting following error while runnin juptyer notebook from ananconda prompt

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Please let me know the solution to fix it as didn't find much on google.
Faced this error while trying to start jupyter notebook from anaconda.
But can open it from cmd.
Environment variables of anaconda are properly configured.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ankit Chawrai\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\Ankit Chawrai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 51, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\Ankit Chawrai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\Ankit Chawrai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Ankit Chawrai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Ankit Chawrai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\Ankit Chawrai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\Ankit Chawrai\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always launch Jupyter Notebooks from either from the Windows menu or the Anaconda Navigator.  Almost always from the Windows Start Menu.

When I installed Anaconda a shortcut was created within the Start Menu, and when clicked it launches a cmd window, runs some scripts and then opens the Jupyter Explorer page within my default browser.